# How to process broadcast Intent in parallel/concurrent way

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

In the Acitity I am trying to receive broadcast  Intent  "android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE ". After receving intent from the client side I give the filename to asynctask. (single hreaded)

Push File:

```
executeCommand((new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c","adb push D:/gunmachine/adb_direct_push.mp3 /data/local/tmp/adb_direct_push.mp3"}));
```

SendBroadcast:

```
executeCommand(new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c","adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE" + " -d " + "file://" + "/data/local/tmp/adb_direct_push.mp3" });
```

Client Side:

Client push the file.
Client sends broadcast with the filename push.
Client parse broadcast intent result and get the resultcode.

Android side:

Start receiver in the activity onResume.
Receive the file name from broadcastreceiver.intent when received MEDIA_SCANNER.. Action
Send file name to asynctask for further processing.
Send result to main thread and setResult()

Client side output:

Command : adb push D:/gunmachine/adb_direct_push.mp3 /data/local/tmp/adb_direct_push.mp3
Exceuted Runtime command
[100%] /data/local/tmp/adb_direct_push.mp3
D:/gunmachine/adb_direct_push.mp3: 1 file pushed. 0.4 MB/s (35158 bytes in 0.089s)

Command : adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE -d file:///data/local/tmp/adb_direct_push.mp3
Exceuted Runtime command
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE dat=file:///data/local/tmp/adb_direct_push.mp3 }
Broadcast completed: result=200

Here,

200 is the result embeded from the application side.

In single thread this is all working fine. Please let me know how to implement multithreading here in aplication side.

OnResume code:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        Log.v("METADATA_APP", "Registering the actiivty ");

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
                Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        intentFilter.addDataScheme("file");

        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {            

@Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.v("METADATA_APP","Received onReceive message" );
            String procFilename = intent.getDataString().replace("file://", "");
            Log.v("METADATA_APP", "sending file for processing..." + procFilename);
            String respCode = callAsyncThread(procFilename);
            setResultCode(Integer.parseInt(respCode));
        }
    };
    //registering our receiver
    this.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In according with docs you shouldn't run long running operations in onReceive() method :

> Because a receiver's onReceive(Context, Intent) method runs on the
>   main thread, it should execute and return quickly. If you need to
>   perform long running work, be careful about spawning threads or
>   starting background services because the system can kill the entire
>   process after onReceive() returns. For more information, see Effect on
>   process state To perform long running work, we recommend:
>
> Calling goAsync() in your receiver's onReceive() method and passing
>   the BroadcastReceiver.PendingResult to a background thread. This keeps
>   the broadcast active after returning from onReceive(). However, even
>   with this approach the system expects you to finish with the broadcast
>   very quickly (under 10 seconds). It does allow you to move work to
>   another thread to avoid glitching the main thread. Scheduling a job
>   with the JobScheduler. For more information, see Intelligent Job
>   Scheduling.

Comment: Can you please propose a design for the above scenario ? Like where I can call broadcastreceiver and use asynctask.thread_pool_executor